# Gradle compile dependencies after evaluate

Tags: android, plugins, gradle

I'm writing a plugin for android which will automatically download Google based dependencies, for example the famous

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
```

The problem I have is as following:

After project evaluate *project.afterEvaluate()* I am fetching all dependencies

```
project.configurations.compile.getAllDependencies()
```

Then I iterate over the collection in order to find dependency group with name "com.android.support".

If such dependency is declared I download the repository via *android update sdk* binary. So far everything is ok. The script then is evaluating the dependencies and shouts that

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+.
```

The second run results with success since the repository has been downloaded in first run.

Comment: To understand what's going on here, implementation details of your repository download need to be known, and possibly also implementation details of the Gradle Android plugin. Executing the build in a debugger might help.

Comment: I think the important information here is that we are trying to check whether there's a particular dependency specified and, if it is, modify a particular repository (Android). The problem with checking for the dependency is that it evaluates the collection and while we're modifying a repository, it's to late for the collection to see the dependency, we have just added.

Comment: If the source code helps here's the link to github [link](https://github.com/pjakubczyk/android-sdk-plugin)

Comment: Just for the sake of documenting things, there used to be also Jake Wharton's [SDK Manager Plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin) which already does what you're trying to achieve. However, the plugin has been deprecated as the upcoming version 2.2 of the Android Gradle plugin will have this functionality built-in.